# How to implement this Scenario in ER ?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

The company wishes to store the data of its current customers in the database, where each customer has a unique customer ID, name, address, country and country international telephone code. The company also wishes to have a list of future customers, so the company can send them
information about recent special offers. These future customers are nominated by the company employees and can be identified by their emails or telephone numbers. Once a future customer rents his first car, the customer record should be removed from future customer list and added into the list current customer.

should I create two entity for current customer and future customer? or one is enough?

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good idea to move data around, because it is inefficient, slow and unnecessary.

Instead, represent an attribute as a column and update the column.

Keep just 1 table for **Customers** including future customers (prospects). Identify whether a customer is an actual customer or a prospect, using a column : **Cust_type** ('A' or 'P' for example).

Note that a prospect may become a customer and the reverse may also be true (if a prospect places a purchase order and then cancels it, for instance.) You have to keep this status updated.

Keep a separate table for all **Customer Orders**.